# only expanded item showing in kendo treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am working on kendo and .net mvc3. My problem is when I click on the expand button, only the expanded item is showing, but I want it to look like a hierarchy folder:

[image]
before parent folder clicked

### ----

[image]
when i click expand button

### ----

Here is my code:

```
function OnSelectTree(Id) {
    var treeview = $("#PathTreeView").data("kendoTreeView").dataItem(Id.node);
    var treeview2 = $("#PathTreeView").data("kendoTreeView");
    console.log(treeview.Id);
    //treeview2.dataSource.read("Read", "ManagePhoto", new { path: id });
    treeview2.dataSource.read({ Id: treeview.Id });

   @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
.Name("PathTreeView")
.DataTextField("Name")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "ManagePhoto"))


)
.ExpandAll(true)
        .Events(e => e
                    .Select("OnSelectTree")
            //.DataBound("OnSelectTree1")
                    .Expand("OnSelectTree")
            )
```

and controller

```
   public JsonResult Read(string Id)
        {
            string FileRepository = db.SystemParameter.Where(n => n.Key == "FileRepository").Select(n => n.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            //const string StartDirectory = @"D:\SOKMUpload\Upload";
            Id = Id ?? FileRepository;
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(Id).Select(file =>
                 new DownloadPhotoViewModel
                 {
                     Id = file,
                     hasChildren = false,
                     Name = Path.GetFileName(file)
                 });

        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(Id).Select(dir =>
             new DownloadPhotoViewModel
             {
                 Id = dir,
                 hasChildren = Directory.GetFiles(dir).Any() || Directory.GetDirectories(dir).Any(),
                 Name = Path.GetFileName(dir)
             });

        var result = files.ToList();
        result.AddRange(directories);
        result = result.OrderBy(x => !x.hasChildren).ToList();
        return this.Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

thankyouuu, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Did you try the [demo code](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview) provided by kendo ui to build your treeView? It seems like a pretty ordinary tree you have there, so maybe try that out.

Answer (score 0):

(my reputation is to low to comment :( ).
The problem right now (I think) is that you are replacing the whole datasource with only the subtree, and not adding it to current datasource?

I also believe that you will run into problem if someone alters the dirs/files while someone is expanding (because you use a numeric count to tell where to expand?

Please checkout [telerik demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/remote-data-binding) and I don't like to post path's to controller, but I think it's the easiest way to do it to ensure that the file structure hasn't changed...